# Comments enable rich text

Tags: kiwi-tcms

We tried to insert picture to record the result for each passed test case in one test run. However, cannot find a good way. For the test comment at the right-handside, is there way to enable rich text and allow to paste picture?

Answer (score 0):

> We tried to insert picture to record the result for each passed test case in one test run

This is tracked in https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/1954 as a feature request. Subscribe on GitHub to follow the progress.

> For the test comment at the right-handside, is there way to enable rich text and allow to paste picture?

Not at the moment but it can be done. Please open a feature request at https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/new/choose so we can track this functionality.